# How to bookmark the whole file in Vim, not a specific line?

Tags: vim

#### Use Case

- I open file A, go to line A1
- I bookmark it
- I go to another line A2 in the same file
- I open file B
- I navigate to the bookmark
- A is opened at line A2, not at line A1

Comment: You could simply use `:ls` and avoid having to memorize anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that with (uppercase) file marks by just considering the buffer number; i.e. instead of recalling the (exact marked) position via `A`, do

```
:execute 'buffer' getpos("'A")[0]
```

As Vim remembers the last position in the buffer, it'll take you there, not to the marked position.

Comment: Very clever! `nnoremap <c-p> :execute 'buffer' getpos("'" . nr2char(getchar()) )[0]<cr>`

Answer (score 2):

Marks are used to go to a specific line, column, and file in which they are set. That is there purpose.

Options that might work for you:

- Set a upper case mark, e.g. `mA`
- Use a buffer navigation command, e.g. `:b foo` (`:b` can take partial filenames)
- Use a fuzzy finder to jump to your buffer
- Remember the buffer number and use it directly `:b 12` (avoid this)
- Use `<c-o>` to go back to the buffer
- Use `<c-6>` to jump to the previous buffer
- Use a split so you can see both buffers at the same time
- Open the buffer in a new tab (I tend to avoid tabs)

Personally I would just set another uppercase mark or use `:b`.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `~/.vimrc`:

```
nnoremap <c-m> :execute 'buffer' getpos("'" . nr2char(getchar()))[0]<cr>
```

Then just bookmark the file using `mX`, and jump to the last position in it using `<c-m>X`.

Comment: This solution is by [Wiener Boat](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3281758/wiener-boat), based on [Ingo Karkat’s answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27906925/578288). I moved it out of the question into its own answer.

Comment: Note that `<C-m>` equals `<CR>`, which may cause problems in the quickfix and command-line windows.